# Get url value from varnish

Tags: regex, url, rest, varnish, legacy

I want to strip out values from a url in varnish, so I can take different actions based on the url, for example:

URL: /product/123/price/available.

I'd like to convert this to /products?id=123&sort=price&available=true

I would also like to be able to (if this is possible), set values on the request header, so instead of passing all the params on the URL, I could do the following:

/products?id=123&sort=price

- with header: **x-show-available-only: true**

I appreciate the second example appears a bit odd, but this way we could pass new params back to our legacy application, and ensure none of the new params interfere with current params - we would just read new params via the header, until we migrate all our functionality to our new platform.

I'm sure it's a regex thing, but can't work out how to do it.

Comment: Before posting an answer, am I correct in thinking are moving from one app (with the old url scheme) to a new one (with the new scheme), and that both these are going to run side-by-side for while? Do you want to generate the new URL scheme in both apps, but rewrite requests to URLs that are going to the old app, back to the old format?

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much spot on!  We will be bringing on some new functionality straight away, then migrating parts of the application as the new functionality becomes available.

Comment: Therefore - stage1, both old & new urls, go to old & new apps. Stage2, once all references to the old urls get removed from the apps, we will implement redirects for old urls (for bookmarks, links, etc.). Stage3, once fully migrated to new app, and we see no more use of the old url schema, we will remove all rewrite rules.  I hope that makes it clearer.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is NOT tested, but should be close enough that you can tweak it to get it right.

Based on your URL:

```
/product/123/price/available
```

You'll need to specify two backends (change the IPs for your own ones):

```
backend old_app {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
}

backend new_app {
    .host = "127.0.0.2";
    .port = "80";
}
```

And the code in your vcl_recv:

```
if (req.url ~ "^/product/") {
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "/product/([0-9]/)/([a-zA-Z])", "/products?id=\1&sort=\2");
    set req.backend = old_app;
} else {
    set req.backend = new_app.
}

if (req.url ~ "/available") {
    set req.http.x-show-available-only = "true";
}
```

You can add more regex rules as if/else blocks.

Good luck!

Comment: If the answer is correct, can you please mark it as so? Thanks! :-)